# Reading tuple data from file with varying types

Tags: python, python-3.x

everybody. I'm trying to read in this data set and then convert it to a traversable tuple in python.

```
(
 (
  (0, 1),
  (q0, q1, q2),
  q0,
  (q2),
  ((q0, 0, q0), (q0, 1, q0),(q0, 0, q1),(q1, 1, q2))
 ), 
 ()
)
```

The issue seems to be that the datatypes cross and it can't just be scrubbed and read in.

Thanks for any help yall can give!

Edit:
Current, albeit small, non-working code:

```py
filename = "dataset1.txt"


with open(filename, 'r') as dataset:
    data = ""
    for line in dataset:
        data += line.strip().replace(' ', '')
    print(data)

    print(tuple(data))
```

which generates the output

```
('(', '(', '(', '0', ',', '1', ')', ',', '(', 'q', '0', ',', 'q', '1', ',', 'q', '2', ')', ',', 'q', '0', ',', '(', 'q', '2', ')', ',', '(', '(', 'q', '0', ',', '0', ',', 'q', '0', ')', ',', '(', 'q', '0', ',', '1', ',', 'q', '0', ')', ',', '(', 'q', '0', ',', '0', ',', 'q', '1', ')', ',', '(', 'q', '1', ',', '1', ',', 'q', '2', ')', ')', ')', ')', ',', '(', ')', ')')
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: "the datatypes cross and it can't just be scrubbed and read in" - what do you mean by this? The data looks like a bunch of nested tuples, is that what you want in Python as well? And are all the values strings, or do `q0` etc. refer to values you want to substitute in from elsewhere?

Comment: the datatypes being crossed meaning q0 would be a string and 0 or 1 would be an integer. 0 and 1 can be strings though, and yes a nested tuple would be perfect.

Comment: @Grismar added details in comment above

Comment: The input has 1 more `)` than `(`?

Comment: @Timus Yeah we just got that fixed. Making the change now

Comment: That file does not contain tuples.  It contains strings.

Answer (score 1):

Python has a built-in abstract syntax tree library, [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html), that allows you to walk though python code. The challenge here is that you have string like `q0` that python interprets as names. This is easily handled by replacing all of those with strings, then evaluating the tuple:

```
import ast

s = '''(
 (
  (0, 1),
  (q0, q1, q2),
  q0,
  (q2),
  ((q0, 0, q0), (q0, 1, q0),(q0, 0, q1),(q1, 1, q2))
 ), 
 ()
)'''

class Names2Strings(ast.NodeTransformer):
    def visit_Name(self, node):
        return ast.copy_location(ast.Str(s=node.id), node)

tree = ast.parse(s, mode='eval')        
data = eval(compile(Names2Strings().visit(tree), filename="<string>", mode="eval"))
```

`data` will be the tuple structure you want:

```
(((0, 1),
  ('q0', 'q1', 'q2'),
  'q0',
  'q2',
  (('q0', 0, 'q0'), ('q0', 1, 'q0'), ('q0', 0, 'q1'), ('q1', 1, 'q2'))),
 ())
```

note: in python `(q2)` is *not* a tuple. It's just a single value and the output reflects that.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a standard format, so the only reliable way is to parse it one character at a time with special processing for parentheses and commas. And whenever you get a token, you try to convert it to an int, and keep it as a string if you can.

So IMHO, you have to build a custom parser here.

Here is a possible code that will parse an iterator giving one character at a time:

```
def tup_parse(it, top=True):
    def gettok(toklist):
        token = ''.join(toklist)
        try:
            token = int(token)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        toklist.clear()
        return token
    data = []
    toklist= []
    lastisparen = False
    try:
        while True:
            c = next(it)
            if c == '(':
                data.append(tup_parse(it, False))
                c = ')'
            elif c == ')':
                if len(toklist) > 0:
                    data.append(gettok(toklist))
                return tuple(data)
            elif c == ',':
                if not lastisparen:
                    data.append(gettok(toklist))
            elif str.isspace(c):
                pass
            else:
                toklist.append(c)
            lastisparen = (c == ')')
    except StopIteration:
        if not top:
            raise
        if len(toklist) > 0:
            data.append(gettok(toklist))
        return tuple(data)
```

If you want to parse a string (say `s`), you can use it directly:

```
tup = tup_parse(iter(s))
```

If you want to parse a file, you can first build a character generator:

```
def genit(fd):
    while True:
        c = fd.read(1)
        if c != '':
            yield c
        else:
            return
```

and then use:

```
tup = tup_parse(genit(fd))
```